# encoding error: Your input contains only whitespace

Tags: qgis, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I tried to sent request to server Overpass API:

```
req.body()= "(node(51.249, 7.148, 51.251, 7.152);< ;);out meta;";
```

I got this error:

> The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL.
>
> Error: encoding error: Your input contains only whitespace.

Comment: Where and how are you executing this request? I can see the result for the area of Wuppertal https://overpass-turbo.eu/.

Comment: i execute this request using boost::beast,i use in my code this server :https://lz4.overpass-api.de/api/interpreter, in general what can the cause that generate this error

Comment: Please post a full reproducible example, otherwise we can't help you. As the query itself is working ok, this is likely some issue in your code executing the query.